# HTML5 Video - Fallback Linked Image

Tags: css, html

I'm looking to display a linked image to show when my video isn't compatible.

My code is as follows:

```
<video controls poster="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.png">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/image/CRM-Systems-Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<a href="http://content.workbooks.com/free-trial-workbooks-crm?utm_source=Homepage&utm_medium=laptopimage&utm_campaign=laptophomepage">  
  <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/crm-system-image.png" title="CRM System image">
  </a>
</video>
```

However when I use Browser Stack to test IE8 (non compatible with `<video>`) no image is shown? Is this due to the link?

**Browser shots link:** http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/663ccadc9d1c2a3aa880fb4e1ef111c4eb386c79

Comment: You can easily check that for yourself by removing the link and testing it with just the `img` tag. What are the results?

Comment: Works fine? Note: The edit on the code.

Comment: Was just about to post that your `img` tag wasn't properly formatted. Looks like you've got it sorted, so.

Comment: I think it might be best to add a boilerplate HTML5 to your code as older IE simply ignores anything in tags that it doesn't recognise. Add `document.createElement("video");` in a JS declaration before anything else, it still wont play a video but it will display what it can inside (ignoring any `source` files). I have not been able to test this, but give it a try. **Correction**: tested and posted.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the start of your `<head>` will do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("video");
</script>
```

This tricks IE8 into recognising the `<video>` element, as IE does not display any tags it does not recognise. I tested this and the link appeared, although `<source>` files are ignored.

Heres an example (you should see nothing on modern browsers, but browsers lacking `video` support will display a text):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("video");
</script>
```

```html
<video>
<a href="#">You are on an older browser</a>
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post and full explanation. Our CMS is Drupal so I added the script into the <head> using a module "Add to head". However the backup image still seems to fail on IE8: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/12cd82cbbaee4171d4cb058dc9f174ca886c75b6

Any advice?

Comment: It seems to be more of a broken image link actually, as the image is clearly there but not found... Have you checked the paths?

Comment: Agreed, the path works fine. I thought the link may be interfering but that's not it either.

Comment: @user2675205 Actually, when I test with browserstack IE8 on Windows7, it displays a macbook, so from my end that seems to be working...

Comment: How odd, do you have a link?

Comment: @user2675205 Don't know how to get a link and its a company account so I can't really provide you with it, but trust me, I can see it.